# How can you import data that has hex strings using Mongo import?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoimport to import a json file. In one of the fields there is potentially regex expressions that contain hex strings such as:

```
{ "field1" : "/\x01\x02\x03/" }
```

I am getting the following error "FailedToParse: Hex escape not supported"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using double escape, what you have fails JSON validation.

```
{ "field1": "/\\x01\\x02\\x03/" }
```

This passes validation at http://jsonlint.com/

You may have to create a special case in your code for setting and getting this value, there is also an escape notion of \u in JSON which I believe denotes a hex escape but I've never used it before.

From some research I found this handy bit of info and example.

```
// Store RegExp pattern as a string
// Double backslashes are required to put literal \ characters in the string
var jsonObject = { "regex": "^http:\\/\\/" };
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. It's a pain because this is a bunch of exported data that I now need to update. But, at least I know the issue and a workaround.